# How do I make the links in my page vibrate when the mouse goes over them?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to get this fiddle to work on my site

http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Ca273/

I changed the CSS to this to make the vibrating effect and I added this css code to my website.

```
a.navlinkOff {
    font-family: Arial !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.navlinkOver1 {
    font-family: Arial !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a.navlinkOver2 {
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode !important;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

I tried adding ids and classes to the navigation menu but for some reason it still doesn't work. The code doesn't do anything at all.

```
<div id="navleft">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="tops.html" id="navlink1" class="navlinkOff">Tops</a></li>
    <li><a href="bottoms.html" id="navlink2" class="navlinkOff">Bottoms</a></li>
    <li><a href="hoodies.html" id="navlink3" class="navlinkOff">Hoodies</a></li>
    <li><a href="accessories.html" id="navlink4" class="navlinkOff">Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="clearance.html" id="navlink5" class="navlinkOff">Clearance</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I'm wondering if it'd be simpler to just make all the links on the site vibrate. I also tried changing the javascript to be like this

```
var navlinks = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

But that still doesn't work on my site.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in Firefox.

Comment: Looks like somebody is fixing a legacy system to work now that firefox is removing :blink: :)

Comment: Before you ask "How can I?", you should ask yourself "Why would I?".

Comment: You don't have to have IDs for all your links, you could use the ´class´ like this ´document.getElementsByClassName('navlinkOff');´ http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Z46z4 or use ´getElementsByTagName("a")´ and add the classes with javascript

Answer (score 2):

like, this...for example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes thumb {
    0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    50% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.9); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}

a:hover
{
    -webkit-animation-name: thumb;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

http://www.cssreset.com/css3-webkit-animation-shake-links/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your hover state css selector using the :hover pseudo selector.

a:hover
{

}

Also I would recommend not using the !important directive, that is a sign of other issues with your CSS structure.

Comment: Yes, the ´!important´ were added because of the OP comment: "It didn't work. I think the problem may be that I'm using an external style sheet and that may be overriding anything I try to do with JavaScript"